# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS wireless not working

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, broadcom, lts

So I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my Dell studio 1555 and my wifi was working before but after a recent update and upgrade, it stopped working. Here are the contents of my wireless-info.txt file on this link:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9612017/

My additional drivers window says i'm using a Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source, but I can't seem to access or detect any wifi access points. Any help will be appreciated as I really would like to have my wifi up and running again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe the STA driver is correct. Please obtain a temporary internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and tell us if your wireless is working.

Comment: This is the output i get when i run the first line: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 204-5ubuntu20.9) but 204-5ubuntu20.7 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).